# Break up XML into parts using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am given XML as input that I have no control over the structure. I need to break the XML up into parts and process each part separately. Below is a very simplified version of a file that I would process.

I am trying to use the grouping functionality of XSLT 2.0 to break up this XML by using the `<breakEle>` tag as the part boundaries. The `<breakEle>` can appear at any level too. Is what I'm trying to do even possible with XSLT 2.0? I have been successful in accomplishing this with XSLT 1.0 using Muenchian grouping but I want to get away from that if we can.

Sample input:

```
<item class="poem">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>paragraph 1</p>
            <breakEle groupNum="1"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Paragraph in another div.</p>
        </div>
        <breakEle groupNum="2"/>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>1st line</p>
                <p>2nd line</p>
                <br/>
                <p>3rd line</p>
                <p>4th line</p>
                <page n="100"/>
                <p>5th line</p>
            </div>
            <breakEle groupNum="3"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</item>
```

What I'm trying to work with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newRoot>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="breakEle">
                    <div num="{@groupNum}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy>
        </newRoot>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would like to end up with something like this:

```
<newRoot>
    <div num="1">
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
    </div>
    <div num="2">
        <p>Paragraph in another div.</p>
    </div>
    <div num="3">
        <h4>header</h4>
        <p>1st line</p>
        <p>2nd line</p>
        <br/>
        <p>3rd line</p>
        <p>4th line</p>
        <page n="100"/>
        <p>5th line</p>
    </div>
</newRoot>
```

Comment: What is the expected result here? -- "*I have been successful in accomplishing this with XSLT 1.0 using Muenchian grouping*" Why not post that?

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry I should have included that at first. I updated it, thanks!

Comment: The logic is not apparent from the example. Why doesn't the third group contain a `div`?

Comment: The <breakEle> can appear at any level. I threw together the sample input randomly because that's what it's like. I'm assuming you were talking about the sample input?

Comment: I am talking about the logic of the required transformation. You said you wanted to "break up" the given XML - but there are parts of the source that are missing from the result,  namely all the `div` elements.

Comment: Oh I see, that would be in line with your comment on your solution about it only handling leaf elements. I asked a question on your solution about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet returns the expected result when applied to the given example.

It works under the assumption that each group should only contain leaf elements.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <newRoot>
        <xsl:for-each-group select=".//*[not(*)]" group-ending-with="breakEle">
            <div num="{current-group()[last()]/@groupNum}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::breakEle)]"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </newRoot>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow that simple? And yes, I failed to mention that the groups wouldn't only contain leaf elements. Your solution does answer my posted question. If the groups did not just contain leaf elements would that change much? I can ask a separate stack overflow question if that would be better. Thanks again!

Comment: I just realized you were the one to help me through this using XLST 1.0. Just wanted to say thanks again for you time. Anyway, I had removed the [not(*)] predicate but it causes the same pieces of the input to process multiple times. I'll keep messing with it and if I can't figure it out I will post again.

Comment: We need a better definition of the problem - specifically what should happen to a wrapper when a breakEle splits it in the middle.

Comment: Yup you are right. I will need to refine this but you have answered my immediate question, thanks!